contour plot changes if range changes
I have a question about making a contour plot with matplotlib.
If I try to plot the same function with two different ranges of the variables (the second contains the other one), I obtain two different plots.
The function:
tData = np.linspace(0,2,11)
yData = np.array([0.99, 0.81, 0.71, 0.55, 0.50, 0.42, 0.24, 0.32, 0.17, 0.26, 0.19])
def dydt(t,y,beta):
    return -beta*y

def funD(y0, beta, tData, yData):
    res = solve_ivp(dydt, [tData[0],tData[-1]], [y0], t_eval=tData, args=(beta,),rtol=1e-6, method='RK45')
    err = 0
    for i in range(tData.shape[0]):
        err = err + (yData[i]-res.y[0,i])**2
    return err

Here is the code:
First plot:
ygrid = np.linspace(0,2,100)
betagrid = np.linspace(0,2,100)
z = np.ones((100,100))
for i in range(100):
    for j in range(100):
        z[i,j] = funD(ygrid[i], betagrid[j], tData, yData)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cnt = ax.contour(ygrid,betagrid,z,1000)


Second plot:
ygrid = np.linspace(0,2,100)
betagrid = np.linspace(0,4,100)
z = np.ones((100,100))
for i in range(100):
    for j in range(100):
        z[i,j] = funD(ygrid[i], betagrid[j], tData, yData)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cnt = ax.contour(ygrid,betagrid,z,1000)


I tried to overlap them, but they do not correspond.
ygrid = np.linspace(0,2,100)
betagrid = np.linspace(0,2,100)
z = np.ones((100,100))
for i in range(100):
    for j in range(100):
        z[i,j] = funD(ygrid[i], betagrid[j], tData, yData)
        
ygrid1 = np.linspace(0,2,100)
betagrid1 = np.linspace(0,4,100)
z1 = np.ones((100,100))
for i in range(100):
    for j in range(100):
        z1[i,j] = funD(ygrid1[i], betagrid1[j], tData, yData)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cnt = ax.contour(ygrid,betagrid,z,100)
cnt1 = ax.contour(ygrid,betagrid,z1,100,alpha=0.5)

two plots
I tried also with a simpler function:
def func(x,y):
    return x**2+y**2

ygrid = np.linspace(0,2,100)
betagrid = np.linspace(0,2,100)
z = np.ones((100,100))
for i in range(100):
    for j in range(100):
        z[i,j] = func(ygrid[i], betagrid[j])
        
ygrid1 = np.linspace(0,2,100)
betagrid1 = np.linspace(0,4,100)
z1 = np.ones((100,100))
for i in range(100):
    for j in range(100):
        z1[i,j] = func(ygrid1[i], betagrid1[j])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cnt = ax.contour(ygrid,betagrid,z,100)
cnt1 = ax.contour(ygrid,betagrid,z1,100,alpha=0.5)

And this is the result:
plot

Add your overlapping code as well, this will help identifying the problem and answering better.

Thanks for your comment. I've exported the two plots and overlapped them on paint.

Paint? Why not simply do it in python? Change the color in python for better visibility. Overlapping two plots shares the same x and y axes. However, you might need to play with the transparency parameter "alpha" in the print statement.

Updated the question

Seems better than the previous vesion, shouldn't it be how you wanted? Looking at the axis of the individual figures, the overlapped one looks okay to me. If you are still not satisfied, make sure the axis are same for the plots, seems you are messing up with betagrid.

Here is the correction, you should do to have a consistent overlapping plot.
cnt = ax.contour(ygrid,betagrid,z,100)
cnt1 = ax.contour(ygrid,betagrid,z1,100,alpha=0.5)


Thanks, I tried in this way but they still do not fit

How does it look like?

Updated the question


The real issue was, you exchanged the axis, or conversely you have not transposed the z array. In the following code, I transposed z.
Your code does not benefit from Numpy array manipulation capabilities, so I took the liberty of rewriting your code.
While rewriting your code I noticed that you were numerically integrating the homogeneous differential equation y' = -βy, but for y(0)=y₀ the solution is just y(t) = y₀ exp(-βt) so I've used this fact while writing my code.
Eventually, to have a complete match between the two plots, I've used an array of fixed levels for both the contours.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
# Outer Product
OP = np.multiply.outer

tData = np.linspace(0,2,11)
yData = np.array([0.99, 0.81, 0.71, 0.55, 0.50, 0.42, 0.24, 0.32, 0.17, 0.26, 0.19])

ygrid = np.linspace(0, 2, 201)
betagrid0 = np.linspace(0, 2, 201)
betagrid1 = np.linspace(0, 4, 401)

z0 = np.sum((yData-OP(ygrid, np.exp(OP(-betagrid0, tData))))**2, axis=2)
z1 = np.sum((yData-OP(ygrid, np.exp(OP(-betagrid1, tData))))**2, axis=2)

levels = np.linspace(0, 20, 101)

fig, (z_2, z_4) = plt.subplots(2, layout='constrained')

cnt0 = z_2.contour(ygrid, betagrid0, z0.T, levels=levels)
plt.setp(z_2, xlabel='y', ylabel='β', ylim=(0, 4))
z_2.axhline(2, ls='--', color='k', lw=0.8)
cb0 = plt.colorbar(cnt0, ax=z_2)

cnt1 = z_4.contour(ygrid, betagrid1, z1.T, levels=levels)
plt.setp(z_4, xlabel='y', ylabel='β', ylim=(0, 4))
z_4.axhline(2, ls='--', color='k', lw=0.8)
cb1 = plt.colorbar(cnt1, ax=z_4)

plt.show()

Should you prefer β in abscissa and y in ordinate,


Addendum

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from math import exp

t = [0.2*n for n in range(11)]
y = [0.99, 0.81, 0.71, 0.55, 0.50, 0.42,
     0.24, 0.32, 0.17, 0.26, 0.19]

(b, y0), _ = curve_fit(
    lambda t, b, y0: [(y0*exp(-b*τ)) for τ in t],
    t, y, p0=[1.0, 1.0]
    )
print('b=%.6f, y₀=%.6f'%(b, y0)) # ⇒ b=0.901200, y=0.984258

plt.scatter(
    t, y, s=18, color='red', label='Data points',
    )
plt.plot(
    t, [y0*exp(-b*τ) for τ in t],
    lw=0.6, color='firebrick',
    label='Best fit: $y(t) = %.3f·\\exp(-%.3f·t)$'%(y0, b),
    )
plt.xlim((0, 2)) ; plt.ylim((0, 1)) ; plt.grid(1)
plt.legend()
plt.show()

